# Find the number of solutions $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Find the number of solutions $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$ for the following equation:

$$a_1 + a_2 + \dots+ a_n = m$$

Where we are given that:

- $a_i \in \{x, x+1\}$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$
- $x$ is some natural number

I know that if $x=0$, then $a_i \in \{0,1\}$, and then the solution is easy by having $m$ numbers from $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$ to be $1$ and the rest as $0$. But is that the only possible way of having a solution for the equation? If so, why then?

Comment: Hint: consider the problem of finding the number of solutions of $b_1 + b_2 + \cdots + b_n = w$, where $b_i \in \{0, 1\}$ and $w = m - nx$. Note that this can be solved using binomial coefficients/combinations. Then show this problem is equivalent to the original problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will attempt doing that. Thanks again!

Comment: You can get a properly spaced and vertically centred ellipsis between binary operators using `\cdots`.

Comment: @MarkSaving, thanks for the help! I got the answer